# JAVA Pass new () object to a Feign Client method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a feign client method ***createFile(FileDto file, ProcessDto process, boolean new)***.

```
@Api(value = "Operations with files")
@RequestMapping("files")
public interface FileResource {

    @PostMapping(value = "createFile")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    FileDto createFile(
            @RequestParam("file") FileDto file,
            @RequestParam(value = "process", required = false) ProcessDto process,
            @RequestParam(value = "new", defaultValue = "true") boolean new);
```

If I call this method with new object creating - ***feignClient.createFile(file, new ProcessDto(), true)*** - I get the following error:

> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'ru.project.hw.ProcessDto';
>
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized
> token 'ProcessDto': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object
> or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')  at [Source:
> (String)"ProcessDto(id=null, system=null)"; line: 1, column: 21]

It works fine with ***feignClient.createFile(file, null, true)*** and if I create ProcessDto object before calling the method ***feignClient.createFile(file, processDto, true)***.

Please explain, is it necessary to create an object before calling feign client method if I need to pass an empty object? Is there any way to make it work with ***new ProcessDto()***? (I have a feeling that passing null as a parameter is not a good idea).

Thanks!

Comment: How does your controller looks like?

Comment: @Nemanja I have a resource (it's a microservice) and it looks the same

Comment: Ok, how to you call that endpoint? I mean, how to you  pass those parmeters that you expect? Can you provide screenshot from postman?

Comment: @Nemanja I call it from another microservice like this: feignClient.createFile(file, new ProcessDto(), true). Here is what I see in the logs: /files/createFile?file =%7B%22resultFileName%22%3A%22VK_Contract_VBK_20220809%22%2C%22uuidMap%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&process=ProcessDto%28id%3Dnull%2C%20system%3Dnull%29&new=true

Comment: Maybe there is something that I should add to "consumes" in @PostMapping(consumes = "...")?

Comment: Ok, how does the endpoint /files/createFile that should handle request looks like?

Comment: @Nemanja I have updated my code insert in the question (public interface FileResource). I hope I understood you well.

Comment: Ok, please upload your feing client configuration